# Show $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$ by using Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to show the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$ by expanding the corresponding Taylor series?

---

**My approach:**

I know that the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ converges uniformly on a closed interval $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ where $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small.

So let be $$S_n(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}(x-1)^k\frac{1}{k}\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}(x-1)^k\frac{1}{k}=\ln(x)\\
T_n(x):=(x-1)+\sum\limits_{k=2}^n(-1)^{k}(x-1)^k\frac{1}{(k-1)k}\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)=(x-1)+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}(x-1)^k\frac{1}{(k-1)k}\overset{?}{=}x\ln(x),
$$
where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n(x)$ denotes the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ at $x=1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)$ the Taylor series of $x\ln(x)$ at $x=1$.

What I can observe so far is that $T_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(0,1+\delta)$ (the point $x=0$ doesn't cause problems anymore) and this allows us to swap limit taking:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to0}T_n(x)=0.
$$

However, I don't know what the limit function is or in other words how to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)=x\ln(x)$.

---

Any suggestions how to complete the proof?

Comment: You don't want sufficiently near $1$, but sufficiently near $0$.  There is no Taylor series for log near $0$.

Comment: $S_n(x)$ is the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ at point $1$. I don't understand why $x=1$  should cause any problems as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n(1)=\ln(1)=0$

Comment: what is $T_n$??

Comment: $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynom of $n$-th degree of $x\ln(x)$ at point $1$

Comment: @Phillip I see. But note that the expression $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}(x-1)^k\frac{1}{(k-1)k}$ is not defined for $k=1$

Comment: @Masacroso Ouh, thanks for the remark I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to keep in mind the geometric series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-x)^k = \frac 1{1-(1-x)} = \frac 1x$$
which is valid for $x \in (0,2)$.  You have that the Taylor expansion $$\ln x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k(x-1)^k$$ is valid on the interval $(0,2)$ but is **not** uniform on any interval of the form $(0,\epsilon)$. However you can conclude that $x \ln x$ is bounded on $(0,1)$ because if $0 < x < 1$ then
$$|x \ln x| = \left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}kx(x-1)^k \right| \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty x(1-x)^k = 1.$$

You can finish up rather quickly if you are willing to use a law of logarithms. If $0 < x < 1$ then $0 < x^{1/2} < 1$ too and $$|x^{1/2} \ln x| = 2 |x^{1/2} \ln x^{1/2}| \le 2$$ so that $$|x \ln x| \le 2|x|^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Can your statement: "$\ln x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k(x-1)^k$ doesn't converge uniformly on the open interval $(0,\epsilon)$" be infered from the following reasoning: we have $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k(x-1)^k=-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(1-x)^k}k$. Then let be $c\in(0,\epsilon)$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $x_n:=1-c^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where again $x_n\in(0,\epsilon)$. As $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(1-x_n)^k}k\geq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c}k$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we know by comparison test that $-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(1-x)^k}k$ diverges. Or is there a simpler argument you had in mind?

Comment: Each Taylor polynomial is bounded on $(0,2)$, but their pointwise limit is not. Therefore the convergence can't be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this question still didn't produce the answer the OP is missing (badly). First off: the Taylor series of $x\,\ln x$ around $x=1$ is indeed (correcting a typo from above) $$x-1+\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k\,(k-1)}\,(x-1)^k.\tag{1}$$ That can be done (as the OP did) by multiplying the known series for $\ln x$ by $x=1+(x-1)$, or directly by calculating the derivatives at $x=1$, observing $$\frac{d}{dx}\,x\,\ln x=\ln x+1.$$ Whether (1) really converges to $x\,\ln x$, is another question, but if we assume (as the OP obviously did) that the series for $\ln x$ converges for $x\in(0,2)$, their derivation shows that (1) converges in that interval, too. Otherwise, we might just estimate the remainder term to come to the same conclusion.

Concerning the limit as $x\to0$, we have Abel's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), saying that $$\lim_{x\to0} x\,\ln x=-1+\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac1{k\,(k-1)}=-1+\sum^\infty_{k=2}\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=-1+1=0,$$ since the series on the RHS converges.

Comment: How nice it is.