# Computing $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \log(x)$ using Taylor or asymptotic expansions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

To compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \log(x)$ one usually resorts to Hôpital's theorem which is often looked down by many in favour of Taylor's theorem which is a more flexible tool with many generalisations and applications.

However, in this specific case, since $\log(x)$ is not defined at zero we cannot consider the Taylor expansion at that point.

> Is there a way to compute the above limit without Hôpital and  using instead Taylor's expansion?

Another way (not exactly Taylor but essentially the same idea) would be to use  [asymptotic expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) of $\log(x)$ for $x\to 0$, these make sense even if $0$ is not in the domain of $\log$.

However I do not know of any asymptotic expansion that might be helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't use l'Hospital nor Taylor but simply  $x=e^{-y} \implies x\log x =-\frac{y}{e^y}$.

Comment: @user ok, but  the question asks explicitely  to use Taylor, which you cannot apply neither to  $y/e^{y}$ for $y\to +\infty$.

Comment: I supposed that, my comment refer to your first period "*To compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \log(x)$ one usually resorts to Hôpital's theorem which is often looked down by many in favour of Taylor's theorem*".

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4036125/505767

Comment: @user thanks, that of Umberto P. is an interesting answer in that post, indeed he shows how one can compute a limit at a point $x_0$ even using Taylor expansion at another point $x_1$.

Comment: Yes this is an interesting idea!

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain $$
0 \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } \frac{y}{{e^y }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } \frac{y}{{1 + y + \frac{{y^2 }}{2} +  \ldots }} \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } \frac{y}{{\frac{{y^2 }}{2}}} = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{y} = 0
$$